# How do I link C source files together using headers

Tags: c, bash, header

C code on the left, bash window on the right

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhTyZ.jpg]

I am trying to create a new .c file by putting **#include "name.h"** at the beginning of my file but as you can see I'm getting an error.

It's saying that it cannot find the include file. Am I not linking them together correctly using the bash commands?

Comment: Huh? You need to have a `main()` function somewhere in your program....

Comment: Please, post the code here.

Comment: Please don't post text as pictures. Copy-paste the text into the question instead.

Comment: And the full text not a few functions at the top

Comment: Error could be net beans directory not set properly, but according to the gcc output nothing is wrong with the include. The error is you compiled Bourne without the main.c file and c requires a main function as an entry point.

Comment: All the ".c"  files I have don't have a main( ) function so I don't see why that would be the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You use the right commands, but you need to have a `main()` function somewhere in your code in order for your program to compile.

Also, you do not need to put `#include "name.h"` to create a .c (source) file, .h file (headers) are used to declare your functions so you can use them in other source files.